# How to exit from TCL proc, without exiting process running inside that proc

Tags: tcl, expect

In the following program, I want to capture the packets in 2nd proc, while ping is running in 1st proc. Now if I execute this program, proc is running ping and exit that. Any idea to to resolve this issue?

My TCL code :

```
proc connect {} {
    global spawn_id
    spawn telnet $1.1.1.1
    expect "*ogin:"
    send "admin\r"
    expect "*word:" 
    send "test\r"
    expect "*>"
    send "ping 30.1.1.2\r"  ; # Ping here
    expect "*#"
}

proc pktcap {} {
    spawn telnet $2.2.2.2
    expect "*ogin:"
    send "admin\r"
    expect "*word:" 
    send "test\r"
    expect "*>"
    send "enable\r"
    expect "*#"
    send "service pktcap on interface vlan 2\r"  ; # capture here, see the ICMP packets
    expect "*#"
    set data $expect_out(buffer)
}
```

Comment: completely untested: try launching ping in the background: `send "ping 30.1.1.2 & \r"`

Comment: Asynchronous operations with expect? `expect_background` may be relevant, but the code can't be written straight-line like that. I've no idea if expect and 8.6's coroutines work well together… but I wouldn't be surprised if not.

Comment: Hi glenn, thanks for your comment. yes. send "ping 30.1.1.2 & \r" works if its linux machine. I am using cisco router, its not supporting & feature.

Comment: Hi Donal, Thanks a lot for your comment. expect_background is working fine without proc.

Answer (score 3):

Use "pipe" syntax of `open` command. Like this: `open "|ping 30.1.1.2" r`. The only (minor) problem is that the file descriptor returned from the `open` command needs to be closed by you - it won't close automatically when the process finishes. Here you have more examples: [Tcl's wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2196)

Comment: Hi Googie, Thanks for your answer. If I use open "|ping 10.1.1.2\r" , yes, ping command is running background. But Once ping is completed, packet capture starts after that. I want to run pktcap when ping is running (to capture those ICMP packets). Please suggest me if you have any ideas.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You say that the ping is already running in background (using "pipe open"), so what is stopping you from running pktcap immediately after openin "ping pipe"?

Comment: I want to run both ping and pktcap simultaneously. Now once ping is completed then only pktcap starts. is it possible to specify ping should run in background continuously while pktcap is running?

Comment: When you execute `open "|ping 30.1.1.2" r` it runs in the background, continuously, right? So you can immediately start `pktcap`, which will run simultaneously.

Comment: No, ping is NOT running continuously. Its also exists when proc is getting exit. When I run the same script without proc its working fine as shown below:

Comment: No, ping is NOT running continuously. Its also exists when proc is getting exit. is there any possibility to prevent this (process inside proc should run, even proc exists) When I run the same script without proc its working fine as shown below:   
spawn telnet <ip>
expect "*ogin:"
send "test\r" expect "*word:" 
send "testr"
expect "*>"
send "enable\r"
expect "*#"
send "ping <ip>\r"
expect_background "*#


spawn telnet <host2>
expect "*ogin:"
send "admin\r"
expect "*word:" 
send "test\r"
expect "*>"
send "enable\r"
expect "*#"
send "service pktcap on int vlan 2 filter icmp\r"
expect "*#"